# Oracle JDK in Alpine Linux

Tags: java, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Oracle JDK in Alpine Linux. I did the following

1. Downloaded the [jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz) from Oracle.com and extracted it to `/home/user/jdk/jdk1.8.0_111` folder.
2. Created JAVA_HOME env variable `export $JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk/jdk1.8.0_111`
3. Updated the PATH env variable  `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

When test the installation by `java -version` I'm getting the following error.

```
localhost:~# java -version
-ash: java: not found
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: Take a look: http://superuser.com/questions/972240/unable-to-setup-jre-1-5-on-alpine-linux